# Demonym for someone from the kingdom of D'mt

Tags: ancient-history, africa, kingdom, demonym

D'mt is a little-studied kingdom which lasted from the 10th to 5th centuries BC, in Eritrea and Ethiopia. For further information, you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%CA%BFmt) and just about nowhere else.

The civilization is so obscure that I doubt I'll get an answer, or at least not one more than "there isn't one", but just to try; **Is there a [demonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) historians use to describe people from the kingdom of D'mt?**

If you don't know, a demonym is an adjective describing the native place of a person or thing; e.g. Sumerian, Aksumite, Byzantine or Semitic.

Comment: Demonyms do not always map cleanly to the place name.  Examples: Dutch, Liverpudlian, Mancunian, Oxonian, Manx, Glaswegian, Monegasque.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abyssinian_people suggests pre-Aksumites.

Comment: @AllInOne This hilights a possible shortcoming in the question, as eg Dutch: *Nederlanders zijn de inwoners van Nederland*. The endonym maps very cleanly there, but the exonyms don't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a historian, but here's what I've found from a cursory look at the literature.

There's Pre-Aksumite, but that demonym isn't exclusive to D'MT.

From "Punt and Aksum: Egypt and the Horn of Africa.":

> There are extensive remains of a Pre-Aksumite culture (that is, the kingdom
>    of D'MT in particular) in the area surrounding Aksum, although little has
>    been excavated until very recently at Aksum itself.

From "The First Millennium BC in the Highlands of Northern Ethiopia and South-Central Eritrea: A Reassessment of Cultural and Political Development.":

> Similarly, it is argued that
>    interpretation of the epigraphic evidence as indicating a single 'Pre-Aksumite' state
>    called D'MT is unjustified.

This article argues that there wasn't a single Pre-Aksumite kingdom and even goes so far as to speculate that D'MT might not have even been a state. So I'm not sure how appropriate Pre-Aksumite is as a demonym for D’MT.

There's also the option of just using D'MT as a demonym.

From "Punt and Aksum: Egypt and the Horn of Africa.":

> At this
>    time, a written language was introduced into the D'MT area that seems
>    almost entirely Saba'an in origin, monumental buildings were first
>    constructed in ashlar masonry, and large-scale sculpture was produced.

From "The Development of Ancient States in the Northern Horn of Africa, C. 3000 BC—AD 1000: An Archaeological Outline.":

> In turn, the Sabean title mukarib (mkrb), used in the inscriptions of a few D'MT kings,
>    suggests that the pre-Aksumite state was organized on the Sabean model, but the possible
>    role of the queens may reflect a local tradition and support an indigenous origin of the
>    D'MT polity (Schneider 1976).

I would recommend using D'MT as the demonym since it's more specific, and seems to be used more, unless you're discussing the wider Pre-Aksumite culture.

Sources:

Fattovich, Rodolfo. "The Development of Ancient States in the Northern Horn of Africa, C. 3000 BC—AD 1000: An Archaeological Outline." Journal of World Prehistory 23, no. 3 (2010): 145-75. http://www.jstor.org/stable/25801293.

Phillips, Jacke. "Punt and Aksum: Egypt and the Horn of Africa." The Journal of African History 38, no. 3 (1997): 423-57. http://www.jstor.org/stable/182543.

Phillipson, David W. "The First Millennium BC in the Highlands of Northern Ethiopia and South-Central Eritrea: A Reassessment of Cultural and Political Development." The African Archaeological Review 26, no. 4 (2009): 257-74. http://www.jstor.org/stable/40389405.